Find a value and then return array below it until the criteria isn't met
I have a table that contains transactions made by each of my projects.



Project Code
Project Name
Amount ($)




ABC
Project A
400



Transaction Code: … (11-01-2024)
100



Transaction Code: … (16-02-2024)
100



Transaction Code: … (04-03-2024)
200


DEF
Project B
640



Transaction Code: … (14-02-2024)
150



Transaction Code: … (21-05-2024)
320



Transaction Code: … (30-05-2024)
170



I want to get the monthly transactions made by each project so that I can convert them into this table:



Project Code
Project Name
January
February
March
April
May




ABC
Project A







DEF
Project B








I'm thinking of first using VLOOKUP or INDEX/MATCH to find the project code (some projects have the same name), using that as a base, and then returning all the rows between "Project A" and "Project B" so I can use the date information at the end of the transaction code. I think I could use this to sort the transactions (for example, I need to find the cells ending with "01-2024)" for January). Note that some projects have multiple transactions per month, so the formula must take this into account.
What gets me stuck is the part where I have to find the transaction code between "Project A" and "Project B." I'm thinking of using a formula to find all rows below Project A where Column B starts with "Transaction Code." But how do I get the formula to stop when the criteria aren't met?
I'm not sure if what I want is even possible with a formula, so I don't mind using VBA if necessary. However, I'd like to know if there's an easier way to do this.

Powerquery could be an approach to transform the data in such a way that you could use result for Power Pivot. Aside from that, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Could you add details about the followings: a. Can project names the same with different code? b. Can dates repeat either in same project or different one? c. Can project codes repeat as non-contiguous rows? d. What did you try and with what result?

a. Yes. b. It won't repeat in the same project, but the same date can appear in a different one. c. Project codes are unique to each project and won't repeat. d. I've tried using INDEX/MATCH to find where the transaction code starts. Honestly, I'm not sure how to proceed from there. I've tried searching for what I want to do but I couldn't find anything relevant.

I can only repeat myself: Power Query will very likely fulfill your request. It's worth learning. I created most parts of my solution proposal using the Power Query GUI.

2 simple helper columns and you're home.  The first populate would the Project Code and would check the Project Code and if it's blank, return the previous value in the helper column.  The second would parse out the Date from the Transaction Code and if there wasn't one, then return the previous value in the helper column (2).

If I were you, I would fill all "empty" project cells with the correct value (can be done with a very simple VBA routine). You can use conditional formatting to "hide" the project numbers (just use a formula that compares the cell value with the cell above and set the font color to white). With that you can easily use pivot tables, and your data doesn't get corrupted if you use a Sort.

The following M-Code will prepare the data in such a way that you can use the result for Power Pivot
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInput"]}[Content],
    DataType01 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project Code", type text}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Amount ($)", type number}}),
    FillProject = Table.FillDown(DataType01,{"Project Code"}),
    addColumn = Table.AddColumn(FillProject, "Project", each if Text.Start([Project Name],7)="Project" then [Project Name] else null),
    fillDown = Table.FillDown(addColumn,{"Project"}),
    filterColumn = Table.SelectRows(fillDown, each Text.StartsWith([Project Name], "Transaction")),
    splitColumn = Table.SplitColumn(filterColumn, "Project Name", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"("}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Project Name.1", "Transaction Date"}),
    removeBracket = Table.ReplaceValue(splitColumn,")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Transaction Date"}),
    DataType02 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(removeBracket,{{"Transaction Date", type date}}),
    removeColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(DataType02,{"Project Name.1"})
in
    removeColumn

The output resp the result will look like that

The individual steps in the M code strongly depend on the input, meaning the row containing Project A etc., should always look like that. The same applies to the row containing Transaction .... (11-01-2024). The pattern should always be the same; otherwise, the code will break.
Power Pivot result will look like that (sorry, it is in German as I have not switched my Excel language settings).

PS The following M-Code only relies on the assumption  that all the rows which contain a transaction start with Transaction
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="tblInput"]}[Content],
    DataType01 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Project Code", type text}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Amount ($)", type number}}),
    FillProject = Table.FillDown(DataType01,{"Project Code"}),
    addColumn = Table.AddColumn(FillProject, "Project", each if Text.Start([Project Name],11)="Transaction" then null else [Project Name]),
    fillDown = Table.FillDown(addColumn,{"Project"}),
    filterColumn = Table.SelectRows(fillDown, each Text.StartsWith([Project Name], "Transaction")),
    splitColumn = Table.SplitColumn(filterColumn, "Project Name", Splitter.SplitTextByEachDelimiter({"("}, QuoteStyle.Csv, true), {"Project Name.1", "Transaction Date"}),
    removeBracket = Table.ReplaceValue(splitColumn,")","",Replacer.ReplaceText,{"Transaction Date"}),
    DataType02 = Table.TransformColumnTypes(removeBracket,{{"Transaction Date", type date}}),
    removeColumn = Table.RemoveColumns(DataType02,{"Project Name.1"})
in
    removeColumn

Further reading: About Power Query Power Query Documentation

Thanks for the quick reply. I have a minimal knowledge of programming, let alone power query. But if I understand the code correctly, I assume all project names must start with "Project" for this to work? Which isn't the case, unfortunately.

Yes, that is the assumption. The other way to do it to rely on the assumption that all the rows which contain a transaction start with Transaction

After trying to customize the code with my table, I finally got it to work. I have a question though, is the Project Column supposed to list the Transaction Code when using the second alternative? I can still use this result, but projects with the same names are usually related to each other. It'd be nice if I could see the sum of those instantly with pivot.

I'm not sure what you mean. I did not change the names of the columns, so in the Power Query steps, you'll see columns with the name Project Name.1 which contains transaction data. However, this does not impact the outcome. You can, of course, change the output of the PivotTable by selecting different entries for the rows, or you can add another PivotTable with the results you want.

I found that my mistake was not changing the number "11" in row 5 to suit my table. Thank you so much for the help!

Ah, ok. 11 is the length of the text Transaction


Note that I have the regional setting that has a function separator = ";" the more common is to use ",". So maybe you need to adust.
D2 =IF(A2<>"";A2;D1)

E2 =IF(A2="";MID(B2;25;2);"")

I3 =IF(LEN(MATCH(I4; {"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"}; 0))=1;"0";"")&
MATCH(I4; {"January";"February";"March";"April";"May";"June";"July";"August";"September";"October";"November";"December"}; 0)

G5 =UNIQUE(A2:A9;FALSE;TRUE)

H5 =XLOOKUP(G5;A2:A9;B2:B9;"";0;1)

I5 =SUMIFS($C$2:$C$9;$D$2:$D$9;$G5;$E$2:$E$9;I$3)


Give a try to this VBA
Sub Project_Piv()
Dim base As Range
Set base = Range("G4")
col_offs = base.Column + 1
row_offs = base.row
rows_cnt = Range("B1").End(xlDown).row
base.Resize(rows_cnt, 14).Clear
head = Array("Code", "Name", "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")
base.Resize(1, 14) = head
For i = 2 To rows_cnt
  If InStr(Cells(i, "B"), "Pro") > 0 Then
    row_offs = row_offs + 1
    Cells(row_offs, col_offs - 1) = Cells(i, "A")
    Cells(row_offs, col_offs) = Cells(i, "B")
  Else
    mo = Mid(Cells(i, "B"), InStr(1, Cells(i, "B"), "-") + 1, 2)
    Cells(row_offs, col_offs + mo) = Cells(row_offs, col_offs + mo) + Cells(i, "C")
  End If
Next i
End Sub

Define base as the top left cell of the result. Now it is cell G4.
In the names only within the date can contains the "-" character.
The month value is always two digits.
The data field cannot contains empty row, and at the end of it an empty row is needed.
The generated table looks like this:


Here is a Power Query that creates your entire table using M Code.
It depends on

Project Code not repeating
Transaction Date always enclosed within parentheses (dd/mm/yyyy) and no other parentheses in the cell.

Please read the code comments and explore the Applied Steps to better understand the algorithm.
let

//Change next line to reflect your actual table name in Excel
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Projects"]}[Content],

//set the data types
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{
        {"Project Code", type text}, {"Project Name", type text}, {"Amount ($)", Int64.Type}}),

//add a date column by extracting the date between parentheses
//  normalizing to the start of the month
    #"Add Date Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","Date", each if Text.Contains([Project Name],"(")
        then Text.BeforeDelimiter(Text.AfterDelimiter([Project Name],"("),")") else null),
    #"Changed Type with Locale" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Add Date Column", {{"Date", type date}}, "en-150"),
    #"Month Start" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type with Locale", {{"Date", each Date.StartOfMonth(_), type date}}),

//Remove now irrelevant transaction code rows 
    #"Remove Transaction Codes" = Table.ReplaceValue(
        #"Month Start",
        each [Project Code],
        each [Project Name],
        (x,y,z) as nullable text=>if y = null then null else z,
        {"Project Name"}),

//Fill down Project Code and Name for easier grouping
    #"Filled Down" = Table.FillDown(#"Remove Transaction Codes",{"Project Code", "Project Name"}),

//Remove unneeded "null" date rows
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Filled Down", each ([Date] <> null)),

//Group by Project Code, Name and date so we can SUM dates that are in the same month
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Filtered Rows", {"Project Code", "Project Name", "Date"}, {
        {"Sum", each List.Sum([#"Amount ($)"]), type nullable number}}),

//Create a list of all possible month start dates to allow columns for Dates with no data
    #"All Dates" = 
        let 
            Start = List.Min(#"Grouped Rows"[Date]),
            End = List.Max(#"Grouped Rows"[Date])
        in 
            List.Generate(
                ()=>[dt=Start],
                each [dt] <= End,
                each [dt=Date.AddMonths([dt],1)],
                each [dt]),

//Pivot on the Date column
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Grouped Rows", 
        {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), 
            List.Transform(#"All Dates", each Text.From(_)), "Date", "Sum", List.Sum),

//Rename the column names from full date strings to just the month
//  Could make it month and year if you prefer
    #"Rename Headers" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Pivoted Column",
    List.Zip({List.Transform(#"All Dates", each Text.From(_)),List.Transform(#"All Dates", each Date.ToText(_, "MMMM"))}))
in
    #"Rename Headers"



With XMATCH, REDUCing

Fill values for project code and name by looking in reverse direction, using wildcards:
XMATCH("?*",…, XMATCH("Project *",
Though the results could be obtained by using converted as input for pivot tables, added reducing for fun
Didn't attempt with PIVOTBY as it is not widely available yet

=LET(
    data, A2:C9,
    prj_code_with_blanks, INDEX(data, , 1),
    name_and_date, INDEX(data, , 2),
    amount, INDEX(data, , 3),
    indices, SEQUENCE(ROWS(data)),
    converted, DROP(
        REDUCE(
            "Converted rows",
            indices,
            LAMBDA(acc, cur,
                LET(
                    p, INDEX(data, cur, 1),
                    prj_code_filled, IF(
                        LEN(TRIM(p)) = 0,
                        INDEX(
                            TAKE(prj_code_with_blanks, cur),
                            XMATCH("?*", TAKE(prj_code_with_blanks, cur), 2, -1)
                        ),
                        p
                    ),
                    n_d, INDEX(data, cur, 2),
                    prj_name_filled, IF(
                        ISNUMBER(SEARCH("Transaction", n_d)),
                        INDEX(
                            TAKE(name_and_date, cur),
                            XMATCH("Project *", TAKE(name_and_date, cur), 2, -1)
                        ),
                        n_d
                    ),
                    date_string, IFNA(SUBSTITUTE(TEXTAFTER(n_d, "("), ")", ""), ""),
                    transaction_date, IF(
                        date_string <> "",
                        DATE(
                            RIGHT(date_string, 4),
                            MID(date_string, 4, 2),
                            LEFT(date_string, 2)
                        ),
                        ""
                    ),
                    IF(
                        transaction_date = "",
                        acc,
                        VSTACK(
                            acc,
                            HSTACK(
                                prj_code_filled,
                                prj_name_filled,
                                transaction_date,
                                INDEX(amount, cur, 1)
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        ),
        1
    ),
    month_cols, SORT(UNIQUE(EOMONTH(INDEX(converted, , 3), 0))),
    converted_proj_code, INDEX(converted, , 1),
    converted_td, INDEX(converted, , 3),
    converted_amt, INDEX(converted, , 4),
    u_proj, SORT(UNIQUE(CHOOSECOLS(converted, 1, 2))),
    monthly_totals, REDUCE(
        HSTACK("Project Code", "Project Name", TOROW(TEXT(month_cols, "mmm-yyyy"))),
        SEQUENCE(ROWS(u_proj)),
        LAMBDA(acc, cur,
            VSTACK(
                acc,
                HSTACK(
                    INDEX(u_proj, cur, ),
                    TOROW(
                        MAP(
                            month_cols,
                            LAMBDA(m,
                                SUMPRODUCT(
                                    converted_amt,
                                    --(converted_proj_code = INDEX(u_proj, cur, 1)),
                                    --(EOMONTH(converted_td, 0) = m)
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    ),
    monthly_totals
)


